# How can I customize date generation in Jekyll?

Tags: internationalization, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I would like to use Hindu-Arabic numbers in Jekyll i.e. ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰ instead of 1234567890. How can I customize Jekyll to achieve this or which parts of Jekyll should be extended to support this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll outputs date strings with the [`date`](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/v3.0.0/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb#L221) Liquid filter [by default](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/v2.5.1/lib/site_template/_layouts/post.html#L8). To customize this behavior, you need to use a plugin to provide an i18n-aware date formatter (filter) to use in your templates.

For example, take a look at [i18n_filter.rb](https://github.com/gacha/gacha.id.lv/blob/master/_plugins/i18n_filter.rb) which is linked from the [official Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/).

Comment: Could it be possible to change the default presentation ONLY by activating a plugin? With no further changes in my code. I want to make it happen seamlessly.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi Yes, it's possible: override the default filter by naming your custom filter as "date" (`def date(input, format); ... end`) and registering it in the usual way in your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The use of any utf-8 characters is up to the writer. It's content and it's not par of the software. So you have nothing to customize for Jekyll to use Hindu-Arabic numbers natively.

Just check that your charset is present in your html and that it is set as `utf-8`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Nothing more.

Comment: This meta tag is already included in [header part](https://github.com/mehdisadeghi/mehdix.org/blob/gh-pages/_includes/head.html). But as far as I have experienced the coding for ASCII numbers are different from Unicode ones (in this case Hndo-Arabic numbers), therefore I think the software could generate different characters (numbers). Moreover it's jekyll that generates date strings and I don't write them myself.